# c++ Default paramaters: is it possible to override a default parameter without overriding earlier default parameters

Tags: c++, function

I have a function:

```
int function(int a, int b = 1, int c = 2){
    return a+b+c;
}
```

I want to set the value of the "c" variable to 3, but don't want to set the value of "b"

In a language like python I can do this:

```
function(23,c=3)
```

However in c++ I cant find a way to do something like that. All examples I could find involved setting the value of "b" before the value of "c", like this:

```
function(23,1,3);
```

How can I set the value of a default parameter directly?

Comment: You cannot do that directly

Comment: C++ doesn't have that feature.

Comment: You can do this using [Boost.Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) but it involves a lot of macros

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in C++ (at least not directly). You have the provide all parameters up to the last one you want to provide, and in the order given by the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that in C++.

As a workaround you could wrap all parameters as fields with default value in a class (or a struct). You can then have multiple constructors for that class that allow you to set only those fields you are really interested in changing with respect to default.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in c++... if you're willing to jump through some hoops.

For fun, here is an example of how it might be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

//
// utility to check whether a type is in a list of types
//
template<class T, class...Ts> struct is_in;

template<class T, class U>
struct is_in<T, U>
: std::is_same<T, U>::type {};

template<class T, class U, class...Rest>
struct is_in<T, U, Rest...>
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, U>::value || is_in<T, Rest...>::value>
{};

//
// a wrapper around fundamental types so we can 'name' types
//

template<class Type, class Tag>
struct fundamental {
    using value_type = Type;
    using tag_type = Tag;

    fundamental(Type x) : _x(x) {}

    operator const Type&() const { return _x; }
    operator Type&() { return _x; }

    Type _x;
};

//
// a utility to figure out a fundamental type's value or to take it's default value if it's not present
//
template<class Fundamental, class Tuple, typename = void>
struct value_of_impl
{
    static typename Fundamental::value_type apply(const Tuple& t)
    {
        return Fundamental::tag_type::dflt;
    }
};

template<class Fundamental, class...Types>
struct value_of_impl<Fundamental, std::tuple<Types...>, std::enable_if_t<is_in<Fundamental, Types...>::value>>
{
    static typename Fundamental::value_type apply(const std::tuple<Types...>& t)
    {
        return typename Fundamental::value_type(std::get<Fundamental>(t));
    }
};

template<class Fundamental, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) value_of(const Tuple& t)
{
    return value_of_impl<Fundamental, Tuple>::apply(t);
}


//
// some tag names to differentiate parameter 'name' types
//
struct a_tag { static constexpr int dflt = 0; };
struct b_tag { static constexpr int dflt = 1; };
struct c_tag { static constexpr int dflt = 2; };

//
// define some parameter 'names'
//
using a = fundamental<int, a_tag>;
using b = fundamental<int, b_tag>;
using c = fundamental<int, c_tag>;

//
// the canonical implementation of the function
//
void func(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
}

//
// a version that forwards the values of fundamental types in a tuple, or their default values if not present
//
template<class...Fundamentals>
void func(std::tuple<Fundamentals...> t)
{
    func(value_of<a>(t),
         value_of<b>(t),
         value_of<c>(t));
}

//
// a version that converts a variadic argument list of fundamentals into a tuple (that we can search)
//
template<class...Fundamentals>
void func(Fundamentals&&...fs)
{
    return func(std::make_tuple(fs...));
}

//
// a test
//

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    func();
    func(a(5));
    func(c(10), a(5));
    func(b(20), c(10), a(5));

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
0, 1, 2
5, 1, 2
5, 1, 10
5, 20, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly, but you can use [Named Parameter Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom) (although [criticized](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.18)).

The idea is to create an object encapsulating all parameters, initialize it using method chaining and finally call the function, so the code would look like:

```
int v = function(params(23).c(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be done with the named parameter idiom.  Here's how it might look in use to have *optional* parameters (sans the default parameter values):

```
/*
int function(int a, int b = 1, int c = 2){
  return a+b+c;
}
*/

int function( Parameters &p ) {
  /* ... */
}

void someOtherFunction() {
  function( Parameters().parmW(/*...*/)
                        /* parmX was omitted here */
                        .parmY(/*...*/)
                        .parmZ(/*...*/)
          );
```

Adding default parameters could be done in a few ways.  `function` could be replaced with a class whose purpose is to perform those actions.  `Parameters` could also be written to know which flags were set, then `function` passes in default values before it begins executing.  I'm sure there's plenty of ways to do this, perhaps some a lot better than what I've suggested.